# IF formula where the test is a logical value in OpenOffice

Tags: openoffice

How can I do `=IF(E2,-1,1) * D2` in OpenOffice, where `D2` is Currency and `E2` is `TRUE/FALSE`?

Comment: Have you tried different variations of `E2`?  All caps, all lowercase, and finally 0 or 1?  The formula works for me in both Excel 2010 and LibreOffice Calc.  Do you have the `=` before the IF?  Also, are all the cells normally formatted?

Answer (score 1):

Your formula works fine for me in OpenOffice. Where using a comma in Excel, in OpenOffice one [needs to use a semicolon](https://issues.apache.org/ooo/show_bug.cgi?id=116302) in the formula (otherwise one gets `Err508` as the result, and `Error: in bracketing` in the status bar), so I used:

```
=IF(E2; -1; 1) * D2
```

[image]

So: ensure E2 is indeed formatted as boolean (like: if typing "true" will automatically convert the value to upper case "TRUE", and the value is right-aligned by default).

As an aside: the following might be a bit easier to read, but that's just a matter of taste:

```
=IF(E2; -D2; D2)
```

Comment: @fixer, thanks for the edit and just FYI: I just discovered that the `;` is not a regional difference. :-)

Comment: How about that.  Every other spreadsheet maintained compatibility with the formula structure of spreadsheets from the earliest days.  The OpenOffice developers decided to "improve" it.  That kind of stuff just makes life nuts.  It's the reason "tar and feathers" was invented.

Answer (score 0):

You have an incomplete argument as it appears.

As you have it stated, there is nothing to show the logical test for `E2` to be `TRUE` or `FALSE` to anything.

In the cell `E2`, if the value is 0 and you wanted anything with a value of zero or less to be true, you would need to have something that looks like:

```
=IF(E2=<0,-1,1)*D2
```

So, in my example, IF E2 is zero or less, -1(the value if TRUE), if not 1(the value if FALSE) then multiply the result with D2.

The result is simply going to give you a `-1*D2` or a `1*D2` depending on the logical return value of the argument.

Comment: The question states that E2 is True/False.